# How can I use different domains for different localizations using middleman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, middleman

So, I have two localizations - en and es. I want them locate on

***en.site.com*** and ***es.site.com***

or ***site.en*** and ***site.es***

but following this tutorial https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/localization/ I can make only smth like

**site.com/photos** and **site.com/es/photos**

which doesn't look good.

I have source/CNAME file with one line only

```
site.com
```

Maybe I have to do smth with it? If yes, what exactly? I can't find any tutorials or examples at all >< 
Please, help if you know how to use different domains for two localizations in middleman. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I never used Middleman before however I have recently built an app requiring something similar to provide multi-tenancy.

What I did is created a rack middleware layer that will set certain variables based on the incoming request host.  In your case you could set the Rails default_locale for each request or something that configures Middleman to change the locale.

You could do something like this as a very basic implementation:

app/middleware/locale_switcher_middleware.rb

```
class LocaleSwitcherMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)

    if request.host.include("es.")
        I18n.default_locale = :es
    else
        # default to english
        I18n.default_locale = :en
    end

    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

application.rb

```
config.middleware.use "LocaleSwitcherMiddleware"
```